# Getting Experimental support for decorator error when using tsyringe @injectable

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, mocha.js, tsyringe

I'm using tsyringe for dependency injection and trying to run unit tests.
The class is in ts and the test file is in js. When I try to run my tests by executing
`TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"tsconfig.testing.json\" mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.test.js`
I get the following *compilation* error:

```
repo.ts:27:14 - error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.
```

Here is my code.

```
// repo.ts
@injectable()
export class Repo {

  testAdd = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  };
}
```

```
// repo.test.js
const { Repo } = require("../repo");
const expect = require("chai").expect;

describe("testing the add function", () => {
  it("addition worked correctly", (done) => {
    const r = new Repo();
    const res = r.testAdd(4, 5);
    expect(res).to.equal(9);
    done();
  });
});
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

```
// tsconfig.testing.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

If I get rid of the `injectable()` decorator then the tests work.
If I change the test ext from js to ts, then it works.
I tried creating a jsconfig.json and adding in

```
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

but it didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your npm build script look like?

Comment: Personally, I would write tests for a TypeScript project also in TypeScript and not in JavaScript. It is more consistent and avoids issues like this, as you already noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Update, I think the issue is that I needed to add the

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

in the tsconfig.testing.json file as well. So far looks to be working with the .js testing files.